# What does it mean to take the connection form with respect to a tangent field?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, connections

Consider the hyperbolic plane with coordinates $(u,v)$ and metric $\begin{bmatrix}u^{-2}&0\\0&u^{-2}\end{bmatrix}$. For an orthonormal frame field $F_1=u\partial_u$ and $F_2=u\partial_v$, I found the connection form to be $\omega^1_2=-\frac1udv$ using the Cartan structural equations:
$$d\theta^i=\omega^i_j\wedge\theta^j,$$
where $(\theta^i)_i$ is the coframe to $(F_i)^i$ such that $\theta^iF_j=\delta^i_j$.

Let $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ be a unit speed geodesic.

Given a vector field $W=w^ie_i$ and a frame field $(F_i)^i$, we can define intrinsically to the surface the covariant derivative along $\alpha$ of $W$:
\begin{align}
\nabla_{\alpha'}W=\left(w^1\,\!'-w^2\omega^1_2(\alpha')\right)F_1+(w^2\,\!'+w^1\omega^1_2(\alpha'))F_2,
\end{align}
where I used skew-symmetry for the minus sign in the first term.

*But*, I don't know what it means to take $\omega^1_2(\alpha')$. I can't directly substitute $\omega^1_2$ which is found with the structural equations with respect to the coframe, because for $w^i=\alpha_i'$, we have

\begin{align*}
\nabla_{\alpha'}\alpha'=0&=\left(\alpha_1''+\frac{\alpha_2'}{u}dv\right)F_1+\left(\alpha_2''-\frac{\alpha_1'}{u}dv\right)F_2
\end{align*}
which to me doesn't make any sense because of the exterior derivative of $v$ sitting in there.

*So*, what is $\omega^1_2(\alpha')$?

By the way, this is a homework question - please don't give me the answer directly. I am trying to show
$\displaystyle \alpha_1'' -\frac1u (\alpha_1')^2 +\frac1u (\alpha_2')^2 = 0$ and $\displaystyle \alpha_2'' -\frac2u \alpha_1' \alpha_2' = 0$, and I can't for the life of me find how to show this with my expression of $\nabla_{\alpha'}\alpha'$.

Comment: Your equation for $\alpha$ makes no sense. Where is this addition going on? Indeed, you should be writing $\alpha' = \sum c^i F_i$. You're also assuming your frame field is orthonormal. Can you give more specific context for what you're trying to do? Often it's good to work with two different frame fields, differing by an angle $\theta$ of rotation. If you choose the second frame field $\tilde F_1,\tilde F_2$ so that $\tilde F_1 = \alpha'$, then you'll have $\tilde\omega^1_2 = \omega^1_2 + d\theta$. This can be very useful.

Comment: Yeah, it's an assignment question so I was trying not to just ask the question point-blank; I will give clearer detail. I've shown I can choose the frame field to be orthonormal in a previous question (this is the hyperbolic plane). For a diagonal metric [A,0;0,C], $F_1=\partial_1/\sqrt{A}$ and $F_2=\partial_2/\sqrt{C}$. $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ is a unit speed geodesic. I'm trying to show $\alpha_1'' + \frac{A_u}{2A} (\alpha_1')^2 - \frac{C_u}{2A} (\alpha_2')^2 = 0$ and $\alpha_2'' + \frac{C_u}{C} \alpha_1' \alpha_2' = 0$. I hadn't thought of your point of choosing a second frame field.

Comment: coordinate choice is $(u,v)$, so the subscript indicates taking the derivative with respect to that coordinate

Comment: In the hyperbolic plane, you have $A=C=1/v^2$, and the connection form has only one term. If you put in $w^i = \alpha_i’$, this should come out easily.

Comment: yes! this is what I mean - I'm not very good at asking questions, thanks for your patience. Instead of $1/v^2$, we've rotated it so $A=C=1/u^2$. So, I found $\omega^1_2=-\frac1u dv$. If I put this into my expression with $w^i=\alpha_i'$, it just doesn't work out. So my thinking was that taking $\omega^1_2$ with respect to $\alpha'$ meant something different to just taking $\omega^1_2$. Is this right?

Comment: This looks right. If you want to edit your question to include more detailed computations, I'll look at them. (You might also find my differential geometry text, linked in my profile, helpful in general. Although I am totally a moving frames person, I could not teach the course at that level, but there is one section using that approach.)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with more detail :) I'll have a look at your text. If I find it useful, can I share the link to my class mates?

Comment: Of course. So what's wrong is that you're not evaluating the $1$-form on $\alpha’$. You should have $e_i=F…i$? What are $du(F_i)$ and $dv(F_i)$? Now can you finish?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115559/discussion-between-johannes-faller-and-ted-shifrin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had my question answered - I just forgot basic dual/vector multiplication.
For a 1-form $\omega=a\,dx+b\,dy$ and a vector $v=c\partial_x+d\partial_y$,
$$\omega(v)=ac+bd.$$
That's it. I was overcomplicating it.

Comment: Yup. Hard to pin it down until you posted actual work. :)